# Working with cookie in scalaj-http

Tags: http, scala, cookies

I choose the most simple library to work with http https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http However, there is information about working with cookies in its documentation.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no cookie handling in the library. If you want to handle cookies with scalaj-http you will need to parse and generate the `Cookie` and `Set-Cookie` headers yourself.

Other libraries such as [Dispatch](http://dispatch.databinder.net) do have methods for [getting and setting cookies](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/dispatch-scala/m7oWv2YAtjQ/imnkYoCDVUcJ), though you may still have to maintain your own cookie store between requests. If you don't mind using a library not written specifically for Scala, [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) does have good cookie support and can maintain cookies across requests.

Comment: I personally found both scalaj-http and Dispatch largely inadequate for real-world HTTP and would strongly recommend to stick with HttpComponents Client.